# PDO issue in Laravel 4 when using an artisan command

Tags: pdo, laravel, laravel-4, freetds

I am trying to build a artisan command that will connect to a remote MSSQL server, retrieve some records and store them in the local MySQL db.

The query I am performing is `DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('SELECT * FROM Users')`

If I use the above in a blade view, it works. But if I use it in an artisan command, I get the error `[PDOException] could not find driver`

Any help appreciated

Comment: Make sure your terminal PHP has the correct PDO drivers enabled. You can use a different `php.ini` for both web and CLI PHP. Use `php --ini` to see where the `php.ini` file is stored.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the suggestion. Checked to see what ini file it is loading and it looks like it is the same for cli and web. I found a few articles about it. [This one](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/2013/04/06/guide-to-accessing-ms-sql-server-and-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x/) was helpful as it described testing from the cli using `isql` which I was successful, so it can be done from the cli... just not sure how all the pieces fit together